# Invalidate client side caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, static-content, clientcache

I have added caching for static content in my asp.net application

```
<staticContent> 
  <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" /> 
<staticContent>
```

> While pushing new changes to production,The `javascript1.js` its not updating in client's machine. Hence New changes in the JS is not updating

How can i invalidate caching in all my clients browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably just want to disable caching for your pages only and not all items (you prob want to exclude library files like jquery). In that case, you could use the following header

   [System.Web.Mvc.OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

you could add the above header individually or a better way would be to add the  class to a controller and make it the base for all your controllers.

2. If you want to do it for the entire application, you could just add the following in your web config file

   '
       
           
               
               
               
           
       
   '

Comment: how about removing the `static content` in web.config.  Marking all methods as mentioned in the above is redundant. How i specify the same in web config

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. But you could use any one of the two methods mentioned above.

Comment: If i use first option i need to modify all my controllers , thats is not feasibile

Comment: If i want to use web.config pls let me know how i do that

Comment: Add this in web.config file '<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
                <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
                <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>'

Comment: This adds the header telling the browser to not cache any information. This is added to the http response messages.